# onMouseEnter fires repeatedly in react dynamic svg component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In react, I create a dynamic svg where a path and circle component are rendered from a loop:

```
{dimensions.map(function (object, i) {
              return <g>
                <path d={generateBoxPath(object)} clipPath={`url(#${svgID})`} fill='#00000000'></path>
                <circle cx={generateCircleX(object)} cy={generateCircleY(object)} r="20.5" clipPath={`url(#${svgID})`} fill='#00000000' onMouseEnter={() => {handleMouseEnter(i)}} onMouseLeave={() => {handleMouseLeave(i)}} onMouseDown={() => {handleMouseDown(i)}} onMouseUp={() => {handleMouseUp(i)}}></circle>
              </g>
            })}
```

I then have 2 state arrays, one that tracks the scale of the element and one that tracks whether the mouse is clicking the element:

```
const [scales, setScales] = useState<Array<number>>(new Array(dimensions.length).fill(1))
const [mouseDownStates, setMouseDownStates] = useState<Array<boolean>>(new Array(dimensions.length).fill(false))

const updateScaleAtIndex = (index: number, scale: number) => {
    const newScales = [...scales]
    newScales[index] = scale
    setScales(newScales)
}

const updateMouseDownStateAtIndex = (index: number, mouseDownState: boolean) => {
    const newMouseDownStates = [...mouseDownStates]
    newMouseDownStates[index] = mouseDownState
    setMouseDownStates(newMouseDownStates)
}
```

Lastly, I have 4 mouse event handling functions (the ones that are called in the SVG's circles)

```
  const handleMouseEnter = (id: number) => {
    if(!mouseDownStates[id]) {
      updateScaleAtIndex(id, 1.1)
    }
    console.log('A' + id)
  }

  const handleMouseLeave = (id: number) => {
    updateMouseDownStateAtIndex(id, false)
    console.log('B' + id)
  }

  const handleMouseDown = (id: number) => {
    updateMouseDownStateAtIndex(id, true)
    updateScaleAtIndex(id, 0.9)
    console.log('C' + id)
  }

  const handleMouseUp = (id: number) => {
    updateMouseDownStateAtIndex(id, false)
    updateScaleAtIndex(id, 1)
    console.log('D' + id)
  }
```

My problem is that when hovering over the circle, the onMouseEnter event fires repeatedly, instead of firing only once.

What might be the problem?